# Inserting date inside a room database

Tags: android, android-room

I want to get the current date in format like **YYYY-MM-DD** so that I can store in the database and later on read from database and work with date like difference between dates etc.

I have tried to use calender instance to get the current date.

```
val calender=Calendar.getInstance()
val date=DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calender.time)
```

But calender instance is returning calendar type data and I want to get date type(Because the I have a typeconverter for date type data)

`typeconverter`

```
class Converters {
@TypeConverter
fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
    return value?.let { Date(it) }
}

@TypeConverter
fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
    return date?.time?.toLong()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want date in **YYYY-MM-DD** format, 
than you don't need instance of `Calendar` or `Date`.

Just use `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(timeStamp: Long?): String? {
        return timeStamp?.let { FORMATTER.format(timeStamp) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(timeStamp: String?): Long? {
        return timeStamp?.let { FORMATTER.parse(it)?.time }
    }

    companion object{

        val FORMATTER = SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd")
    }
}
```

but if you want calendar instances for any reason, this can be handy (though i would suggest you to above (timestamp/string based) method>

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Calendar? {
        return value?.let { Calendar.getInstance().apply { timeInMillis = it } }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(calendar: Calendar?): Long? {
        return calendar?.timeInMillis
    }
}
```